# oEmbed not working in WordPress

Tags: videos, oembed, youtube, video-player, vimeo

I am using custom embed URL for embedding a video. Embedding Youtube and Vimeo working really fine. But only this URL is not working. But if I add via `iframe`it is working. But I need to add this via oEmbed method. Please help.

This is the URL I am working with. https://www.nanoo.tv/link/v/RmqoRVeT

**Note:** If I use the same URL in another web site it is embedding and working really fine and oEmbed is working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Vimeo and Youtube have OEmbed providers and are registered in WordPress. Unless nanoo.tv supports OEmbed and your site has code to register what a nanoo.tv URL looks like and where the OEmbed provider is, it won't be treated as an OEmbed

Comment: Note that WP has oEmbed discovery on by default, so it should find the site if it properly exposes itself as a provider.

Comment: @TomJNowell how can I do that? This URL is loading in other all web sites I tested.